# Does 'git pull origin master' has difference with 'git merge master'?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

Due to the scenario is quite specific, so, I think I have to post a new question.

Assuming that I have 2 branch named 'master' & 'A' separately.

Approach A:
In branch A, use `git pull origin master` then resolve conflicts if any

Approach B:
In branch master use `git pull` to pull latest changes from remote,
then `checkout A` to branch A, use `git merge master` then resolve conflicts if any.

Are these both approaches above has same result?

Comment: Basically the same. But in B, the local `master` could have some commits not pushed yet.

Answer (score 1):

Git pull contains both fetch and  merge.so i am not sure what is you asking.

```
git pull = git fetch + git merge
```

please read this documentation 
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull