# How is it best to solve conflicts in git?

Tags: git, gitlab

I was learning git and wanted to find out what is the best practice to solve conflicts in a project. So far, I know two ways to solve conflicts, firstly, from the newly-created branch we need to do "git pull origin master" then solve conflicts. Secondly, we can return from the newly-created branch to master branch then in master branch do "git pull origin master" then get back to that newly-created branch and do "git merge master". Please can you please help with deciding which approach is better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does 'git pull origin master' has difference with 'git merge master'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082091/does-git-pull-origin-master-has-difference-with-git-merge-master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are in `new-branch` derived from master

   - `git status`
   - `git add .`
   - `git commit -m "My Commit from new-branch"`
2. checkout to master `git checkout master`
3. `git pull origin master`
4. return to new-branch

   - `git checkout new-branch`
5. `git merge master`
6. resolve conflict

Comment: ok but how about doing git pull origin master in new-branch itself without checking out to master. Is that ok?

Comment: @wewq I don't like that. I never do it like that.

Comment: is it like personal preference or is there a problem with doing git pull origin master in new-branch itself without checking out to master?

Comment: Git pull will perform `git fetch` and then `git merge`. 

Personal preference, but also common practice is `git merge master` will always merge master with the default merge strategy because also it will join two or more development histories together and let you keep track of histories of merges. Especially if working with multiple people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git mergetool to resolve the conflict. [mergetool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool)